# Unbalanced tree with document.write() in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

As far as I can tell this is a problem with speculative execution in Firefox.  Here's the entire html demo file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Foo</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

document.write("<table>")
document.write("<tbody>")
document.write("<tr>")
document.write("<td>")
document.write("<textarea rows='10' cols='12'>")
document.write("</textarea>")
document.write("</td>")
document.write("</tr>")
document.write("</tbody>")
document.write("</table>")

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When loaded into Firefox, I get the following message on the console:

```
An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing1 bug.html:22:0
```

I don't believe I'm writing an unbalanced tree.  Can anyone suggest a simple way to avoid this?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Optimizing_your_pages_for_speculative_parsing

Comment: Does the console indicate which line caused the problem? And do you still get the problem if you write all of that html in a single `document.write()` statement? Seems to me that just *not* using `document.write()` is the solution here...

Comment: Document.createElement?

Comment: Can't tell you why a `textarea` in a `table` seems to do this, `document.write("<table><textarea></textarea></table>")` does the same, but you may have heard `document.write` is evil, just don't use it.

Comment: @Oriol I realize that `document.write()` is a bad way to do this.  This is taken from an old application, and in fact I want to convert it to use the DOM methods, which I'm certain will fix this.  But I wanted to clean up any lingering warnings first.

Comment: @epascarello I've already read the cautions listed on that page, and I don't believe I'm doing any of the things it said to avoid.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, the line it gives is line 22, which contains `</script>`

Comment: You use document.write wrong. Look at the source of the page. Only way around the issue is do not use document write. Use methods like appendChild

Comment: @epascarello Ok, so what you're saying is that there is no right way to use `document.write()`, and the only sense in which I'm "using it wrong" is that I'm using it at all, is that correct?  As I said, I want to convert this to use the DOM methods, but I was hoping to eliminate the warnings first.

Comment: Why worry about warnings from code you're replacing? Rewriting this particular bit will be one less warning to worry about in the overall codebase...

Comment: @nnnnnn Well, mostly I just wanted to understand if I'd done something wrong.  My conclusion is that I have not, other than using `document.write` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a special case related exactly to **`textarea` inside `table`**.

`table` alone doesn’t cause the issue, `textarea` inside `div` doesn’t too, `textarea` not inside `table` doesn’t as well.

Probably somehow related to the specific treatment of `textarea` contents (e. g. showing tags as text even if special characters like `<` and `>` are not escaped via entities like `&lt;`/`&gt;`) compared with regular elements.

A relatively easy way to get rid of `document.write()` calls is to create an array (e. g. `parts`) before the code that uses `document.write()` and replace all the `document.write()` calls with `parts.push()`, and then assign `parts.join('')` to `innerHTML` property of the whole container.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't call document.write only once? Like this:

```
document.write("<table><tbody><tr><td><textarea rows='10' cols='12'></textarea></td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

or if you want to keep the breaklines you can use backslash:

```
document.write("<table>\
<tbody>\
<tr>\
<td>\
<textarea rows='10' cols='12'>\
</textarea>\
</td>\
</tr>\
</tbody>\
</table>");
```

EDIT:
Above solutions don't solve the problem soif you only put this into your body:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = "<table>\
<tbody>\
<tr>\
<td>\
<textarea rows='10' cols='12'>\
</textarea>\
</td>\
</tr>\
</tbody>\
</table>";
```

Comment: Same warning is produced in the console in my testing.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't make any difference.  Even with a single call to `document.write` the problem still exists.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara you're right.  I thought the error was caused by the multiple calls of the write function. But I came with a solution, check the edit.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but I don't think I have a convenient anchor point for the table.  It's part of a longer list of html that's being generated.  None of it causes any problems except for this one place with the `textarea` tag.  I just can't understand what's special about this case.